# Java Spring -- Validating individual object fields

Tags: java, spring, validation

It's pretty straightforward to validate all the fields in a object by binding the object to a form and using the `@Valid` notation for the object in the validating controller method.

Let's say I have an update screen that only allows the user to update some of the fields.  Is there away to avoid having manual validation?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the harm in letting validation run against all other fields?  Whose to say that a malicious user wouldn't modify those before they made its way to the server?

Comment: I guess you're right! I had some imaginary harm factor in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a validation against a subset of validation rules, you can use the spring feature of validation groups with [`@Validated`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html)

You will have to define a set of groups for your bean or form model similar to this

```
public class Form {

  public interface Group1 { /*empty interface*/ };

  public interface Group2 { /*empty interface*/ };

  @NotEmpty(groups = { Group1.class }) // associate constraints
  private String field1;               // to a validation group 

  @NotEmpty(groups = { Group2.class })
  private String field2;

}
```

And in your controller, you can use the annotation like this

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/validate1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String updateGroup1(@Validated(Form.Group1.class) Form form, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      // return to the same view
    }
    // return success
  }

}
```

You can find here a good example for it

https://narmo7.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/how-to-set-up-validation-group-in-springmvc/